# Parsing in prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

```
run([H|T]) --> num(H),run(T).
run([T]) --> num(T).
num(increase) --> [increase],{write(1),nl}.
num(decrease) --> [decrease],{write(0),nl}.
```

In this parser when increase is given it prints 1, when decrease given it prints 0. However, there occurs a problem when processing the last element of the list. 
For instance `run(A,[increase],[])` prints two 1's. `run(A,[increase,decrease],[])` prints one 1 and two 0's, a thing which i don't want. How can i make it work properly so that `run(A,[increase],[])` prints 1 and `run(A,[increase,decrease],[])` prints 1,0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both clauses of run//1 match in this case. Consider changing the second clause of run//1 to:

```
run([]) --> [].
```

Independently, consider using phrase/2 (like `phrase(run(A), [increase])`) for portability, instead of assuming a particular expansion method for DCGs.